# SQL query is not working

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, t-sql, ado.net

This code doesn't change the column (I try to increase the column `orderTillNow` value by one...), table: items.

```
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=***:*******.com;Initial Catalog=****;User ID=*****;Password=******;Integrated Security=False;");

using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("UPDATE items SET ordersTillNow = ordersTillNow + 1 ")) 
{
    connection.Open();
    command.Connection = connection;

    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    connection.Close();
}
```

I've tried to put that statement into SQL Server Management Studio - and that works. Why does my C# not change the value?

Comment: don't forget to wrap your connection variable in a using statement too!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your forgot:

```
connection.Open();
```

In the end your code should look like this:

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("..."))
using (SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
{
    command.CommandText = "...";

    connection.Open();

    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
} // will close the connection automatically
```

And note:

`using`-block against `SqlConnection` is much more important then against `SqlCommand`.

Comment: Why your note? I would have thought the using block against the reader that may come out of `ExecuteReader` most important - since you can have multiple commands, multiple connections but only one active reader unless MARS is enabled. Otherwise just let everything else kick around?

Comment: Thank you. i've tried that and its not working. the table "items" include - id | title | orderTillNow ...... maybe i'm missing somthing on the command ? (anyway, on the sql managmant on the query it's work).

Comment: oh, i forggot to add to the aspx file the Onclick event.

Comment: @todda: I agree with you, thus would prioritize that in next order: reader, connection, command

Comment: @toda - an undisposed connection object results in a connection pool overflow.

Comment: @Nathan: in case of intensive connections opening, i.e. timeout to expire not reaching

Comment: @abatishchev - did you mean that comment for todda?

Comment: @Nathan: rather to both of you, as addition to your comment: not closed connections will exhaust the pool if connections will not be closed by timeout, i.e. in case of rare not-further-closed-connections opening, Right?

Comment: Guys... if i can to disturb.. can you tell me how i'm adding to my code querystring? example: i want that the "orderTillNow" column will update only the item that the costumer is in his page now.. by querystring... (or other way)

Comment: @Bside: `this.Request.QueryString["id"]` will give you id from query string

Comment: I dont remember where to put that... on the top of the button click event?

Comment: @abatishchev - thanks. that will update the orderTillNow only for the id on the parameters.Add..... ?

Comment: @Bside: if you will put parameter to the query: `UPDATE items SET ordersTillNow = @ordersTillNow WHERE Consumer = @ConsumerID` and add that two parameters to the command as I posted above

Answer (score 0):

Have you opened the connection before you execute the query?
What kind of exception (messaage) do you get?

Cheers, Rok

Answer (score 0):

You haven't opened and closed the connection.

```
connection.Open();
connection.Close();
```